# Изменить значения индексов в dataframe, чтобы они начинались с нуля

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, index

После удаления ненужных строк в датафрейме индексы стали `[5, 7, 9, 15, 20]` и т.д.
Можно ли их привести так, чтобы они начинались с нуля?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

наиболее идиоматичный способ:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

или так:

```
df = df.set_index(np.arange(len(df)))
```